# How to set widget properties with `enum` type like `GtkAttachOptions`? I'm trying to simulate `gtk_widget_set_vexpand` to work on `gtk2`

Tags: c, linux, gtk3, gtk2

My project was to create a graphical application to help each employee to create his own list of clients in a central database and the only problem I had was with the compatibility between `gtk3` and `gtk2`. The project from beginning to end is based on `gtk3` and then I realized that there are employees who use a system with `gtk2` only. So I made some modifications to the implementation without much difficulty and works without any problem on its purpose. The last thing that I want to finish, is to simulate the function of the [`gtk_widget_get_hexpand()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-hexpand) and [`gtk_widget_get_vexpand()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-vexpand) ... they are only in `gtk3`. For the other functions to work the same way as in `gtk3`  i did something like this:

```
#define gtk_grid_new() gtk_table_new(1,1,false)
#define GTK_GRID(x) GTK_TABLE(x)
#define GtkGrid GtkTable
#define gtk_grid_attach(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6) gtk_table_attach(x1,x2,x3,x3+x5,x4,x4+x6,GTK_FILL,GTK_FILL,0,0)
```

To let the application work without the `gtk_widget_get_hexpand()` and `gtk_widget_get_hexpand()` functions, simply with:

```
#define gtk_widget_set_hexpand(x1,x2)
#define gtk_widget_set_vexpand(x1,x2)
```

Because is little more complex to simulate these functions with macros i tried to do something like this:

```
inline void gtk_widget_set_hexpand(GtkWidget* widget,gboolean expanded) {
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&value,G_TYPE_ENUM);
    if(expanded)
        g_value_set_enum(&value,GTK_EXPAND);
    else
        g_value_set_enum(&value,GTK_FILL);
    gtk_container_child_set_property(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(widget)),widget,"x-options",&value);
}

inline void gtk_widget_set_vexpand(GtkWidget* widget,gboolean expanded) {
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&value,G_TYPE_ENUM);
    if(expanded)
        g_value_set_enum(&value,GTK_EXPAND);
    else
        g_value_set_enum(&value,GTK_FILL);
    gtk_container_child_set_property(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(widget)),widget,"y-options",&value);
}
```

[`gtk_container_child_set_property()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-child-set-property)

I know that it is not correct! Actually i don't know how to set the `child properties` of the `widgets` and more specific how to create a `GValue` with `G_TYPE_ENUM`. Can someone help me?

UPDATE: @ptomato gave me a better solution on this. Actually by using the [`gtk_container_child_set()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-child-set) function instead of the `gtk_container_child_set_property()` then:

```
#define gtk_widget_set_hexpand(x1,x2) gtk_container_child_set(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(x1)),x1,"x-options",(x2)?(GTK_FILL|GTK_EXPAND):GTK_FILL,NULL);
#define gtk_widget_set_vexpand(x1,x2) gtk_container_child_set(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(x1)),x1,"y-options",(x2)?(GTK_FILL|GTK_EXPAND):GTK_FILL,NULL);
```

does the trick successfully! Thanks to @ptomato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gtk_container_child_set()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-child-set) instead:

```
gtk_container_child_set(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(widget)), widget,
    "y-options", expanded? GTK_EXPAND : GTK_FILL,
    NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I tried to do it this way and basically had the same errors `Gtk-CRITICAL` with `assertion GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container) failed`. Which means is wrong from the beginning. I forgot to write about this

Comment: Make sure the widgets are added to the container before you do this?

Comment: Yes of course are added in the container before. This is the weird. Maybe because this operation is asynchronous? Actually I 'm doing this: widget creation -> container add (on grid or table: attach) -> widget settings

Comment: Well, does it work if you don't use `gtk_widget_get_parent` but just pass a pointer to the parent?

Comment: Yes it works but not as in gtk3 :( . I replaced some of the `gtk_widget_get_hexpand` and `gtk_widget_get_vexpand`function with `gtk_container_child_set` and it works without errors but actually does not expand the widget the same way as in `gtk3` with `gtk_widget_get_hexpand` function. For example, puts the child widget in the center when resizing the window instead of expanding it from edge to edge. I had the same results when i did it with `gtk_table_attach` with `GTK_EXPAND` on both of the `GtkAttachOptions` arguments. This is more complicated than I expected

Comment: Maybe you need to set `GTK_EXPAND | GTK_FILL` to simulate the GTK3 `expand` properties.

Comment: Haha ... was so simple :D . Thank you!